# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s), but I think I do

Tags: c, valgrind

I am fixing a program which should properly title each word in a string, the input is given as `struct pair` which defined as:

```
// A struct to record pairs of strings
typedef struct pair {
    char *first;  // the input string
    char *second;  // the result string
} pair;
```

and heres my fixed version of the method:

```
void process(pair work) {

    int len = strlen(work.first);
    char *temp = malloc(len * sizeof(work.first));  // LINE 22 IS HERE

    // convert all words to lowercase
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = work.first[i];
        if (isupper(c)) {
            temp[i] = tolower(c);
        } else {
            temp[i] = c;
        }
    }

    // title each word
    int last_space = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (last_space && isalpha(temp[i])) {
            temp[i] = toupper(temp[i]);
        }
        last_space = temp[i] == ' ';
    }

    strcpy(work.second, temp);   // LINE 44 IS HERE
    free(temp);
}
```

When I run `$ valgrind --track-origins=yes ./fixed hello`, I get:

```
==25973== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25973== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25973== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25973== Command: ./fixed hello
==25973== 
==25973== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==25973==    at 0x4C2BADB: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:506)
==25973==    by 0x400985: process (fixed.c:44)
==25973==    by 0x400A13: main (fixed.c:59)
==25973==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==25973==    at 0x4C28BE3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==25973==    by 0x400856: process (fixed.c:22)
==25973==    by 0x400A13: main (fixed.c:59)
==25973== 

...(other stuff which seems unrelated)

==25973== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25973== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I do not understand why this happens, I have seem some other answer saying this error is usually due to I have not properly initialize my variable, but I have assign my variable in question `temp` in the loop.

update: my work is initialized and allocated memory here:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pair work;
    work.first = argv[1];
    work.second = malloc(strlen(work.first) * sizeof(work.first));
    if (!work.second) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory");
        exit(-1);
    }

    process(work);

    printf("%s becomes %s\n", work.first, work.second);
    free(work.second);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your `temp` is not null-terminated?

Comment: Aside: `malloc(len * sizeof(work.first))` is incorrect for 2 reasons a) `sizeof(work.first)` is the size of a pointer. and b) off by 1, no room for any string terminator.

Comment: Re the edit, the same fault with allocating memory for `work.second`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ops I have forgotten about that

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes after I added the terminator the error disappear, thanks!

Comment: @WeatherVane do you mind make it a answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: That's not really the answer though, just an aside, because you allocated **too much** memory by considering each element to be the size of a pointer. @EugeneSh. noticed you were not actually writing the terminator.

Comment: @WeatherVane I see, thanks for the helps!!

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for the help!